# PHP JpGraph: The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Tags: php

When I run the file in php file in Firefox 35, it returns the Image cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

apache v2.4.7
php v5.5.9 GD include

```
<?php
           require_once("/jpgraph-3.5.0b1/src/jpgraph.php");
           require_once("/jpgraph-3.5.0b1/src/jpgraph_line.php");
           require_once("/jpgraph-3.5.0b1/src/jpgraph_date.php");
           require_once("/jpgraph-3.5.0b1/src/jpgraph_bar.php");
           DEFINE('NDATAPOINTS',1440);
           DEFINE('SAMPLERATE',1440);
           $graph = new Graph(650,200);
           $graph->SetScale("textlin");
           $graph->SetShadow();
           $graph->AddText($txt2);
           $graph ->title->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_BOLD,8);
           $graph->SetMargin(60,50,10,35);
           $graph->SetScale('datlin');
           $graph->title->Set("$date");
           $graph->xaxis->SetLabelAngle(0);
           $graph->SetImgFormat('jpeg',100);
           $graph->SetBackgroundImage("cpu.jpg",BGIMG_FILLFRAME);
           $graph->SetTickDensity(TICKD_NORMAL,TICKD_SPARSE);
           $graph->xaxis->scale->SetDateFormat('h:i');
           $graph->xaxis->scale->SetTimeAlign(MINADJ_1);
           $line = new LinePlot($data,$xdata);
           $line->SetLegend('CPU');
           $graph->yaxis->HideZeroLabel();
           $graph->xgrid->Show(true,false);
           $graph->xgrid->SetColor('black@0.8');
           $line->SetFillColor('chartreuse2@0.6');
           $line->SetFillColor('lime@0.4');
           $graph->Add($line);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code. At first you should add

```
$graph->Stroke();
```

at the end of your code to output the image.
Besides your variables $txt2, $date and $line are undefined.
JpGraph will output images with error messages inside that can help you to resolve all errors.

---

Reduce your code to something simple like the following, RTM and go step by step to something you intended but haven't explained here.

```
$graph = new Graph(650,200);
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$graph->title->Set("$date");
$graph->title->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_BOLD,8);
$graph->SetMargin(60,50,10,35); 
$graph->SetScale('dateint');
$graph->xaxis->SetLabelAngle(0);
#$graph->SetBackgroundImage("cpu.jpg",BGIMG_FILLFRAME);
$graph->SetTickDensity(TICKD_NORMAL,TICKD_SPARSE);
$graph->xaxis->scale->SetDateFormat('h:i');
$graph->xaxis->scale->SetTimeAlign(MINADJ_1);
$graph->yaxis->HideZeroLabel();
$graph->xgrid->Show(true,false);
$graph->xgrid->SetColor('black@0.8');
$line = array();
$line[0] = new LinePlot(array(1,2,3),array(time(),time()+300,time()+600));
$line[0]->mark->SetType(MARK_SQUARE);
$graph->Add($line);
$graph->Stroke();
```

Comment: Thanks! Аfter I added $graph->Stroke() that's what gives:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method LinearScale::SetDateFormat()
on the line $graph->xaxis->scale->SetDateFormat('h:i')